# Can a Flutter app be built from Xcode alone?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

A Flutter app contains an `ios` directory, which contains a `Runner.xcworkspace` file. That Xcode project contains a `Run Script` build phase that executes `/bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" build`.

Here is my question: When I want to build a release version of my Flutter app, do I need to FIRST run `flutter build ipa` before I kick off the Xcode build? Or is it enough to just run the Xcode build without running any flutter CLI commands first?

I assume it's enough to just build through Xcode because it will execute the Flutter build step as one of its build phases. Is that true?

This link doesn't make it 100% clear whether it's enough to just build using Xcode: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/cd#running-deployment-locally

It lists `flutter build ios --release --no-codesign` and `bundle exec fastlane [name of the lane]` as two subsequent steps at the bottom of the page. Since Fastlane can just trigger the Xcode build, is it really necessary to run `flutter build` first?

Comment: In my experience you need to run `flutter build` because when you do, it not only builds the Xcode project but also builds Flutter/Dart files beforehand and also changes configurations on the Xcode project as well as the creating the `Generated.xcconfig` and other files generated by Flutter. I'm also looking for a way to have Flutter build everything with only Xcode but so far haven't found it. Did you try `flutter assemble`?

Off-topic: have you tried SwiftUI? In my experience it's SO MUCH better, easier and faster do to everything on SwiftUI than using flutter, I wrote many apps on SwiftUI

Comment: By the way you don't need to run `flutter build ipa`, you can just run `flutter build ios` prior to running the build on Xcode